# How to calculate percentage from 2 fields in 2 datasets within ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services

I have an ssrs report that has 2 fields from 2 different datasets. In the pic below I have a count from a query for Total Bound Policies and another query for Total Bound Policies With At-Fault Endorsements and I'm trying to calculate a % value in another column and after googling for solutions I cannot find a solution using lookup or just a division calculation.  Any help/direction would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Here is my design layout:

[image]

Here is my last expression that is getting an error:

[image]

Comment: Jeez, your datasets have long titles.  Is there a common field between the two datasets?  Also, are these report items contained within the same Tablix object?  Or are each in their own Tablix item?  Or is it simply free floating textboxes?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Steve.  
1). There is only 1 field in each dataset each are defined as an INT data type 
because I'm only doing a COUNT for each dataset.
2). They each have their own tablix.  I didn't set them up that is I guess just the default.
3). I inserted a table for each dataset and then the last table I'm just trying to calculate the percentage in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the issue correctly, `Total Bound Policies` and `Total Bound Policies With At-Fault Endorsements` each contain a single result which is a count of each.  I can think of a couple of solutions for this problem, the easiest one of which being adjusting the query to bring all of the data into a single query to return your counts AND a value for the percentage.  It's almost always better to do as much of the calculations in SQL as possible.

```
DECLARE @a INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1)
DECLARE @b INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table2)

SELECT @a AS Count1, @b AS Count2, CAST(@a AS DECIMAL) / CAST(@b AS DECIMAL) AS aPercent
```

As you can see, in SQL, I'm casting each count as a decimal, as division with `INT` values will return a whole number, meaning you'll have either 0% or 100%.  Using some random tables from my database brings back these results when I run this query:

[image]

If this solution isn't a viable option or if I misunderstood the question, another option that could help is to declare each field with it's corresponding dataset.  For example, `(Fields!TotalBoundPolicies.Value, "TotalPoliciesBound")` would get the field from dataset `TotalPoliciesBound`.

Comment: Thank you Steve.  I appreciate your help.  That got it. A lot easier than calculating numbers from 2 different datasets.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.  SSRS can be a real pain when you have multiple datasets, that's for sure.